# Handling Return key in iOS 8 keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm working on an iOS 8 keyboard extension, and currently when the user taps on my Return key I'm running this code:

```
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\n"];
```

This works as expected in most places. However, in the Contacts app, if I edit a contact, select the first name field, and press Return, nothing happens. It does not move to the next field as expected. This is in contrast to the default keyboard, which does move to the next field.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually every textDocumentProxy will have it's UIReturnKeyType. Depending on which the method, used by your Return key should be changed.

```
   typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIReturnKeyType) {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
   };
```

In your case, please implement jump to the next responder if you see that current `self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType` returns `UIReturnKeyNext`

Comment: Yes, but how would I jump to the next responder? This does not seem to be a method that I can call on the textDocumentProxy?

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm looking into it now and it seems that on top of that self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType returns nil always. Perhaps keyboard extension is forbidden access to those properties.

Comment: I haven't had the issue of returnKeyType being nil, though I'm only checking it in the textDidChange: method. At this point I save it locally.

Comment: I have been playing around with returnKeyType in my Keyboard Extension for some time. What can be noted: in most applications returnKeyType returns actual return key type (0, 1 , etc.) In contacts, however, it always returns 0 for me. It may be to the fact, that the value is set to default, which is zero, or maybe property access is denied. However, while checking the Mail application, it also always returns 0, but the return key in the keyboard extension's return key's behavior is different: sometimes it jumps to next field, and sometimes it just makes a new line or does nothing.

Comment: It might indicate, that the returnKey should work fine as long as it inputs @"\n", and that each fields' returnKeyType in Mail app is set, it's just keyboard extension doesn't have permission to access those properties. Could you confirm that?

Comment: Seems to be the case at this end too. I guess we're bumping up against the limitations of what a 3rd party keyboard can do at this point in time.

Comment: You only say that we should implement different kinds of return type, but how to implement them? I can only find a way to add a new line, but not others such as send or search.